# Products not showing in backend

Tags: magento-1.9, products, magmi

I use magmi to import products from external sites which is working and has done for many years.

The problem is that for some reason new products have stopped showing in the Magento admin panel.

I can see up to id 635,533 but nothing above that.

The products are in the database and the import works as expected.

If I change the edit URL like so...
/catalog_product/edit/id/63539/

I can see the edit view of this product.

If I make changes it shows as a success reloads the page but the changes aren't updated.

Did anyone hear of this before?

Comment: can you please check if the category or any other part of the website change are working fine and only have issue in Product update, It might be possible that your server disk space is full and may not allow to save any changes in database

Comment: I updated a custom attribute and worked fine. I have looked in the data base and all entity_int attributes are missing for the new products

Answer (score 0):

Added products are not showing in backend (admin panel) in magento1.9

- update the product display order

Answer (score 0):

Can you please re-index once and check it,

Hope this may help you!!